# Tips to start a siphon without getting a mouthful of water

Tags: watering, water, rain-barrel

I have spent the week setting up my water storage system including a1000L ICB, I am lucky that my allotment is next to one of the large communal water capture and storage areas and with heavy rain predicted for the next week our chairman has told me to feel free to siphon off as much water as I can rather then waste it as the pretty much full communal tanks overflow.

Any tips to starting a siphon off without sucking and ending up with a mouth full of water? I know you can submerge the pipe fully and hold one end sealed as you transfer it but struggling to get this to work consistently and the communal tank has a very narrow opening that I can’t get the whole hose pipe in.

Comment: Turkey baster or a syringe. You need something that'll pull water past the top of the siphon tube. I suspect the items I suggested may not have enough pull for your hose size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeatedly submerge and lift the high end of the pipe to catch water and then let it fall, with the bottom end closed, to fill up the pipe.

Alternatively, use a bulb starter (this one is for an aquarium cleaner): [Python squeeze bulb](https://www.aquacave.com/python-squeeze-bulb-siphon-starter.html)

Or (if improvising in the field) glue a party balloon or pool inflatable - something designed to be inflated - between two boards, seal the neck in airtight manner onto the bottom of the pipe, and pull the boards apart to create suction.